# Why did simply loading bootstrap into my document screw up my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I designed a page. Everything was working fine, and then I was going to add a carousel into a mobile media query in lieu of what I had already had, and noticed that just by loading in Bootstrap all my page got messed up.

What is bootstrap changing, or overriding? Or what does Bootrstrap override by default that I don't know about. I tried googling for an answer for a few hours but couldn't find anything. I even checked an article top 10 common mistakes with bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap has all types of tags and classes defined in it , that's why your page code messed up, you can add Bootstrap before your css link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could potentially have class names that are also bootstrap class names, which would override whichever styles you had on those classes. If you look at the bootstrap documentation you can compare your class names to bootstraps. whichever components of yours are effected, check for similar components from bootstrap and you may just have to change some of your class names.

Answer (score 1):

Double check your media query. You might have set it wrong.
Also, which carousel are you using? Bootstrap carousel? Please upload some attachments for better understanding.